# XSLT max of each group

Tags: xml, xslt

I have data in xml which gives list of products and their prices. Looking for XSLT which can help me to result Max price for each product. Tried may things yet no luck. Please help.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Product>
    <name>P1</name>
    <price>10</price>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <name>P1</name>
    <price>20</price>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <name>P2</name>
    <price>5</price>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <name>P3</name>
    <price>8</price>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <name>P1</name>
    <price>30</price>
  </Product>
</root>
```

Expected output

```html
Product Price
P1 30
P2 5
P3 8
```

Comment: Can you share at least one of the things you have tried, please? Also, can you say whether you can use XSLT 2.0 (or 3.0)? Thanks!

Comment: I am using Microsoft XSLT processor and not able to use for-each-group as it wont support. so looking for solution with 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **XSLT 2.0** it is quite easy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:text>Product Price&#x0A;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Product" group-by="name">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(current-grouping-key(),
        '      ', max(current-group()/price), '&#x0A;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

As you can see, there is needed a `for-each-group` loop,
selecting `Product` elements and grouping them on the value
of child `name` element.

Inside the loop, `current-grouping-key()` function provides the key of the current group
(value of `name` element) and `max(current-group()/price)` computes the
maximal price.

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/pNEhB3c

## Edit following your comment concerning XSLT version

Your task can be accomplished also in **XSLT 1.0**, using so called
*Muenchian Grouping* (for more detailed description search the Web).

The first thing to do is to create a **key**, grouping elements
to be grouped (*Product*) under some **grouping key** (in our case
*name*):

```
<xsl:key name="prods" match="Product" use="name"/>
```

Then the actual grouping can be performed in a `for-each` loop,
using a predicate with a *Muenchian Grouping idiom* inside:

```
[generate-id()=generate-id(key('prods', name)[1])]
```

An additional point of difficulty is that **XSLT 1.0** has so much
limited capabilities, that it even does not have `max` function.

To circumvent this limitation, we have to write a **template**
(I called it *maximum*), which takes a sequence of elements,
sorts them (descending) and outputs the first (maximum) value.

This template is called for `price` children elements of all
`Product` elements from the current group.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:key name="prods" match="Product" use="name"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:text>Product Price&#x0A;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="Product[generate-id()=
      generate-id(key('prods', name)[1])]">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(name, '      ')"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="maximum">
        <xsl:with-param name="src" select="key('prods', name)/price"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#x0A;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="maximum">
    <xsl:param name="src"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$src">
      <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="descending"/>
      <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/pNEhB3c/1

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using Microsoft .net XSLT processor which is not supporting for-each-group and so I raised this query. Sorry I missed to mentioned in my query. Can you help me to try it with XSLT 1.0

Comment: The XSLT 1.0 solution is verbose. `xsl:for-each` with `xsl:sort` is a common idiom for maximum calculation. There is no seed for a named template.

Comment: Of course, XSLT 1.0 solution with *key* is more verbose than my initial XSLT 2.0 solution. This is why I prefer "2.0" version and I started my answer from it. And as far as *maximum* template is concerned, I wanted the "1.0" version to be similiar to "2.0" version, so I came up with such a "replacement" for *max* function, not supported in "1.0" version.